# How do I get customized list as a output in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, hex, ascii

I've this code.

```
character = input("Enter a character: \n")

def ASCIItoHEX(ascii):
    hexa = []
    for i in range(len(ascii)):
        ch = ascii[i]
        in1 = ord(ch)
        part = hex(in1)
        hexa += part
    return hexa

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hexadecimal = ASCIItoHEX(character)
    print(hexadecimal)
```

and it gives me output like this when I enter "1111":

['0', 'x', '3', '1', '0', 'x', '3', '1', '0', 'x', '3', '1', '0', 'x', '3', '1']

but I want my output like this:

['0x31', '0x31', '0x31', '0x31']

How to obtain this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list.append()` instead `+=` to append the whole string. Otherwise the string is treated as sequence and splittet into the characters.

```py
character = input("Enter a character: \n")

def ASCIItoHEX(ascii):
    hexa = []
    for i in range(len(ascii)):
        ch = ascii[i]
        in1 = ord(ch)
        part = hex(in1)
        hexa.append(part)
    return hexa

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hexadecimal = ASCIItoHEX(character)
    print(hexadecimal)
```

Another way would be

```py
hexa += [part]
```

to concatenate the two lists.